# bash: fifo queue with flock

Tags: bash, fifo, flock

Can flock be set up to be a fifo queue instead of "whoever grabs it first" lock?  For instance, if three processes are running the following code:

```
exec 200>/var/tmp/mylock
flock -e 200     # blocks until lock is obtained
echo "($$) has the lock"
sleep 5          # replace with awesome code
echo "($$) releasing the lock"
flock -u 200 && echo "($$) released the lock"
# Other code that doesn't require a lock
```

When the first process obtains the lock, it will enter the sleep.  Then the second and third instances are started and they both wait for the lock.  But even if the second process hits `flock -e 200` before the third process, the third may still execute before the second.  Once the flock is released, it's up for grabs without honoring who tried to acquire it first.

Can this behavior be adjusted so that the first process which tries to acquire a busy lock is guaranteed to be the first one that executes when the lock is released?

Comment: POSIX provides no such guarantees. If contention is so bad that order begins to matter, maybe the processes should be adding themselves to a queue instead of doing their work while holding the lock?

Comment: You can wait in order on a queue in Redis quite easily using a trivial `bash` client... https://redis.io/commands/BLPOP